# GAE HTTP method support

Tags: python, google-app-engine, httpwebrequest

I get an "unrecognized HTTP method" when trying to do a REPORT request using httplib and gae. Is there a workaround available? An httplib patch for gae? Do you I have to find another host in order to do this natively?

According to the docs, only certain fetch actions are valid: GET, POST, HEAD, 
PUT, and DELETE: [http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/ 
fetchfunction.html](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction.html)

Comment: You need some way to violate the HTTP standard, RFC 2616, see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html -- there are eight methods (the 5 GAE supports, plus the obscure OPTIONS, TRACE and CONNECT), there is no REPORT method in the HTTP standard.

Comment: @AlexMartelli There's no need to call something obscure just because GAE doesn't support it :)

Answer (score 4):

httplib on App Engine is a wrapper around the [urlfetch API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html#Requests), which only supports the GET, POST, PUT, HEAD and DELETE methods. I'm afraid you're out of luck unless the API you're accessing supports some sort of X-HTTP-Method-Override functionality.